# Adicionar evento a um elemento na directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Tenho uma directive que dentro dela tem uma lista. Esta lista é preenchida após a resposta bem sucedida de uma chamada ajax. Por esse motivo a minha função link da directive não encontra essa lista assim que a página carrega, somente quando termina a o carregamento do ajax.

Como faço para aplicar eventos de clique nessa lista assim que tiver a resposta do ajax?

Código da directive:

```
function localizationFilter(){
      var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        scope: {
          controller: '=',
          list: '='
        },
        compile: function(tElement, attr){          
          return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var checks = elem.find('li')
            console.log(checks) // não encontra nada
          }
        }
      }

      return directive
}
```

Template da directive:

```
<ul class="filter-subitens-list">
  <li ng-repeat="item in list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{item + $index}}" value="{{item.name}}">
    <label for="{{item.name + $index}}">
      {{item.name}} <span>{{item.total}}</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um exemplo do evento click nesse caso vai remover o item da 'LIST' ao clicar;

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="list.splice($index, 1)" id="{{item + $index}}" value="{{item.name}}">
```

Comment: Mas no meu caso eu preciso chamar uma função ao clicar no checkbox. Eu crio essa função na controller ou na directive?

Comment: @FelipeCoelho você cria na controller.